# license-gradle-plugin

Tags: groovy, gradle

Thanks to reply, I am searching to apply License-gradle-plugin to check headers in my source code.please give me the full script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.5.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'license'
```

I have used this code in my `build.gradle`, but It is not updating headers in my all source file `src/main/*.groovy files`. How can I write build script to check is Header exists in the `.groovy` files if not write header in the groovy files?

Thanks,
kothapeta Raju.

---

I tried as you said but getting the following exception

FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'licenseFormatMain' not found in root project 'license-gradle-plugin-master'.
- Try:
  Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

BUILD FAILED

Thanks,
Raju.

Answer (score 0):

So, [reading the instructions](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin) shows that you:

Put this in your `build.gradle` file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.5.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'license'
```

Create a file `LICENSE` in the root of your project

```
Copyright (C)2013 - Tim Yates

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.

See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
```

Then type

```
gradle licenseFormatMain
```

Comment: gradle licenseFormatMain

Comment: I used gradle licenseFormatMain but getting error Task 'licenseFormatMain' not found in root project

Comment: What version of gradle?  Can you edit your question to post the `build.gradle` file you're using?

Comment: I am using gradle 1.4 version. please help me Tim_yates how to write build.gradle

Comment: @RajuKothapeta Do you have a `build.gradle` file?  If so, edit this question, and paste it in so we can have a look and see what the problem is

Comment: I have written build.gradle as you said and i Run gradle licenseFormatMain

Comment: @RajuKothapeta That's your entire `build.gradle`?  You need to add that to your existing file, not rewrite it with just that

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'nl.javadude.gradle.plugins:license-gradle-plugin:0.6.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'license' in build.gradle

Comment: i dont have an idea to apply license plugin to all my source files src/main/groovy to add headers.please help me complete script how to write build.gradle

Comment: @RajuKothapeta **As I said, edit your question and paste the entire build.gradle file in**, Putting stuff like this in comments is a waste of time

Comment: @RajuKothapeta I added the above to my build.gradle added a LICENSE file and it worked.  I don't know what else to say

Comment: Thanks Tim_yates it worked for me.Sorry to waste your time

Comment: If we want to include other types of files like .js, .xsl, .rptdesign etc.,  to include the license text, what do we need to do?

Comment: @RajuKothapeta Again, [it tells you if you read the instructions](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin#recognizing-other-file-types)...

Answer (score 0):

> FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
>
> What went wrong: Task 'licenseFormatMain' not found in root project 'license-gradle-plugin-master'.
>
> Try: Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

This happen if you don't apply the java plugin. Add this in your build file did the job for me:

> apply plugin: 'java'

**EDIT**:
I'm not able to reproduce this issue by removing this line above !!!